# Calculate elapsed time in C

Tags: c, mpi

I'm new to C and I'm using Linux. I got stuck on this uni task. I need to evaluate program and I need to make a program to show the time elapsed for execution. Here is origin program.

```
/*
 * Simple MPI program to sum the numbers from 1 to 1000
 *
 * The output of this program should look like this:
 *
 * $ mpirun -n 4 ./su
 * node 1 of 4 starting at 251 and ending at 500
 * node 2 of 4 starting at 501 and ending at 750
 * node 3 of 4 starting at 751 and ending at 1000
 * node 0 of 4 starting at 1 and ending at 250
 * The sum from 1 to 1000 is: 500500
 *
 * Author: Kevan Buckley
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi/mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // Rank is which process this code is executing in.
    // Rank 0 is the initial process.
    int rank;
    int size;
    int sum = 0;
    int start, end, accum, i;

    // These lines must appear at the start of any
    // MPI program.
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    // These lines tell MPI that rank and size are values
    // that we want to communicate between processes.
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    // Only compute part of the sum.
    // This splits the work over the different processes.
    start = (1000*rank/size)+1;
    end = 1000*(rank+1)/size;

    printf("node %d of %d start: %d end: at %d\n",\
           rank, size, start, end);

    for(i=start; i<=end; i++){
        sum = sum + i;
    }

    if(rank == 0) {
        for(i=1; i<size; i++){
            // Receive a message from another process.
            MPI_Recv(&accum, 1, MPI_INT, i, 1, \
                     MPI_COMM_WORLD,  &status);
            sum = sum + accum;
        }
        printf("The sum from 1 to 1000 is: %d\n", sum );
    }
    else {
       // Send data to the process at rank 0.
       MPI_Send(&sum, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    // This code must end any MPI program.
    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

This is my updated version of it - [Gist](https://gist.github.com/ummahusla/7434526). I took all time calculations from other code that I was working for. I'm tried a lot of things, but still can't get it working.

Any help would be helpful, thanks!

Comment: Try using `mpi_wtime`.

Comment: Where did you pick this `#include <mpi/mpi.h>` from? I've seen several posts here doing the same and it is plain wrong. Should be `#include <mpi.h>` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to time a part of your program.
Here is a sample code to do just that for parallel programming using `MPI_Wtime`.

```
#include <mpi.h>

double start, finish;

MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);
start=MPI_Wtime(); /*start timer*/

/*put the code you want to time here*/

finish=MPI_Wtime(); /*stop timer*/
MPI_Finalize();

printf("Parallel Elapsed time: %f seconds\n", finish-start);
```

Comment: you were missing a semicolon on `MPI_Finalize()`. it should be `MPI_Finalize();`. It's also best practice and provides better results if you start and stop the timer between `MPI_Init` and `MPI_Finalize`. You should also use an editor (like Eclipse) so you can avoid spending hours on finding missed syntax errors!

Comment: Actually you should remove both `#include <time.h>` **and** `#include <sys/time.h>` and replace them with `#include <mpi.h>`. There, I did it for you.